# Trying to change background from white to black but can't get this timer() method to run, the screen is only white

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm trying to make a simple app that changes the background color so many times a second. For example, here I'm trying to do it every 12.5 ms (how do I enter the .5 part?)

I'm extremely new to programming, and can't figure out how to call this method/timer to start running.

I run the app, and it opens the activity with a white background and nothing happens. 
    Since I'm so new, when I look into the Timer() documentation, I'm not really sure what I'm looking at here.... If someone could help that would be amazing.

```
  import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import static android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.background;

/**
 * Created by Spader on 3/17/2017.
 */

public class FlashingScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //Remove notification bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        //set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)
        this.setContentView(R.layout.flashing_screen);

        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //stuff that updates ui
                      getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

                    }
                    ;
                });
            }
        },0,12);



    }



}
```

Comment: When your screen stays white, chances are that this code simply doesn't do what you expect it to do. So first find out how to really change the background color. And then when that works reliable, then look into timing. And just for the record : the human eye would not notice the difference between 12 and 12.5 ms.

Comment: Good feedback. Do you have any suggestions on how to 'really change the background color'?

Comment: I am not an deep android expert. I would ask Google and start playing around :-)

Answer (score 0):

1.
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); 
 This always set the black color since it is not on a conditional basis. You may want to use a boolean to switch color every time it executes the runnable.

2. You shouldn't use getDecorView(). Instead find the root View from your layout xml and change the color.
3. In Java there is no floating value for times. So you can't have 12.5 ms.